# Strange Ribbon error in Visual Studio when building

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm receiving a strange error in Visual Studio when building my WPF application with .NET 4.5 in Visual Studio 11.

My WPF XAML markup is as follows:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="Fablelane.DesktopApplication.CreateStory"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Create new story" Height="468" Width="526">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon>
            <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenu>
                </RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonTab Margin="0" Header="Format">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Font">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RibbonComboBox>
                            <RibbonGallery SelectedValue="Heading 1"
                          SelectedValuePath="Content"
                          MaxColumnCount="1">
                                <RibbonGalleryCategory>
                                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Heading 1" Foreground="#16ea00" FontSize="20" />
                                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Heading 2" Foreground="#00c6ff" FontSize="18" />
                                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Heading 3" Foreground="#999999" FontSize="16" />
                                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Heading 3" Foreground="#707070" FontSize="14" />
                                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Content" Foreground="#FF606060" />
                                </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                            </RibbonGallery>
                        </RibbonComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <RibbonControlGroup Margin="2">
                        <RibbonToggleButton Label="B"
    FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Padding="2" />
                        <RibbonToggleButton Label="I"
    FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Padding="2" />
                        <RibbonToggleButton Label="U" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Padding="2,2,2,0" />
                    </RibbonControlGroup>
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Margin="0" Header="Options">
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1">

        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Now, when I build, I receive the error:

Unknown build error, 'Method 'get_Command' in type 'System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonGallery' from assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not have an implementation.

When I remove the RibbonGallery element from the code, it compiles and runs just fine.

It should probably be noted that I can easily see the designer view rendering just fine in Visual Studio with the RibbonGallery element inside of it. It just fails during build.

Comment: I had this error.  If I removed the gallery from the xaml and created one in code, I got this warning: Reference to type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll', but it could not be found

Comment: This may be the fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772998/the-type-system-windows-input-icommand-exists-in-both-presentationcore-dll-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this same issue going from 4.0 to 4.8, but we had to remove and re-add the correct system.dll to the references.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like a bug, why don't you use reflector and check if the ICommand's getter is rightly exposed?

Comment: From the error it seems the interface is not implemented, easiest way you can approach is to download the pdb, set symbol path in Visual Studio (disable debug just my code under debugging), then with resharper 5/6 find implementation. If you can't find then report bug I'd say.

Comment: For the workaround implement your the interface yourself and register with the library (though not sure if ribbon library allows you to do so)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a problem.

- I have VS 11 Beta with latest updates.
- Downloaded Ribbon (Oct 2010) from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877
- Create new WPF .NET 4.5 app
- Add reference to System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon
- Paste code from question into app
- Design, build, run, no problem

If I look at the Ribbon assembly using DotPeek, then I can see the Command property

```
public ICommand Command
{
  get
  {
    return (ICommand) this.GetValue(RibbonGallery.CommandProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    this.SetValue(RibbonGallery.CommandProperty, (object) value);
  }
}
```

but then you don't seem to be using it.

Is it worth creating a new test app from scratch?